# Questions about compute shader DispatchThreadID?

Tags: directcompute

```
Texture2D<float> InputTex : register( t0 );
RWTexture2D<float> OutputTex : register( u0 );

// Group size
#define size_x 20
#define size_y 20

// Declare one thread fo r each texel of the input texture.
[numthreads(size_x, size_y, 1)]

void CSMAIN( uint3 DispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
  int3 texturelocation = int3( 0,0, 0 );
  texturelocation.x = DispatchThreadID.x;
  texturelocation.y = DispatchThreadID.y;
  float Value = InputTex.Load( texturelocation );
  OutputTex[DispatchThreadID.xy] = 2.0f * Value;
}
```

**First question:**

In this code, does `DispatchThreadID.x` and `DispatchThreadID.y` have the same value, like thread 17 of x and thread 17 of y?

**Second question:**

Can I write this?

```
 OutputTex[ texturelocation ] = 2.0f * Value;
```

A yes or no answer is sufficient, but if no, please provide a short explanation why.

Comment: It's not clear that what an answer to this question would look like. Are you looking for a yes or no answer?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Yes or no answer for both the questions. If the answer is "No" then a bit explanation.

Comment: Is it yes? I mean Am I right?

Comment: Can't you just try it and see?  At least you could rule out _yes_ on your own?